# Trying to group C3.JS scatter chart Y values by X step

Tags: python, django, c3.js, scatter, quantile

I am creating a metrics page for workflow and I have been asked to create a jittered scatter plot chart, that shows per step (x) how many records where there (each scatter) and how long did they take (y). This is something that is fairly easy to do in JMP but I have had a difficult time figuring out how to do it with C3.js.

I have looked at examples from D3, c3 and charts.js

```
    outliersScatter = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#outliersChart',
        data: {
            columns: [
                        ["FIDB_UPDATE", 0,1,2,3,4,5],
                        ["SSD_BIZOPS", 5,4,3,2,1,0],

                    ],
            type: 'scatter'
        },
        axis: {
                x:{
                    tick: {
                        rotate: -45,
                        multiline:false,
                        culling: {
                                   max: 1
                                },
                        }
                },
            y: {
                label: 'Time'
            }
        }
        });
```

I get a chart but they are not grouped by the column names, so ideally, 
The X would have FIDB_UPDATE listed as the x tick, and above it would be 6 plots at a y access of 0,1,2,3,4, and 5 [(see example image from JMP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3oHK.png)